# need to write htaccess rule for single file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create a htaccess file which want to works for only one file.

My folder has multiple files but need to create works only for file 'sample.xml'.Is it possible to create rule which works for single file?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

this rule should works on 'sample.xml'

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
<job>
  <title>
   <![CDATA[<?php echo date('Y');?>]]>
  </title>
</job>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<Files>` tag to match a single file and have your directive there:

```
<Files sample.xml>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
</Files>
```

Comment: I want to write php tag inside the xml as updated in my post.I caught server error afer include ur code

Comment: Exact same code works fine on my Apache with your `sample.xml` file in my site root. You should check your Apache's `error.log` file for the cause of the error.

Comment: Sorry.I included  <Files sample.xml>AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml</Files> as single line.so it throws server error.Its working as you given format (line by line).Thank you.